# dismiss UIImagePickerController without reloading its rootViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

If I present a `UIImagePickerController` on a childViewController like this:

```
-(void)presentImagePicker{
    UIViewController *childVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [self addChildViewController:childVC];

    ImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[ImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    [childVC presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I dismiss the childView:

```
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    NSArray *childVCArray = [self childViewControllers];

    [[childVCArray firstObject] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

the rootViewController is re-initialized.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: None of your code to present or dismiss the image picker controller is correct. Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: because i tried and tried and i ended up here... i also presented it on the viewController itself. no difference.. it gets re-initialized as well.. i don´t know how to do this and honestly i´ve got no clue at all. i´m just using sprite kit, so..

Comment: To start, the proper way to dismiss the image picker is to simply do `[picker dismissViewController:YES completion:nil];`.

Comment: i tried this at first.. same problem

Comment: I think the issue might be related to memory, IDR, i faced similar issue way back.